# Saving only time stamp without date to data frame column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to save only time stamp without date to spark dataframe.
    good_data_df.withColumn("timeStamp",to_timestamp(col("timeStamp"),"HH:mm:ss 
    z"))

Output of above method is 1995-07-04 :16:04:12 ,

But expected output is only 16:04:12 without date, In format i have mentioned only "HH:mm:ss" still date is also stored.

Please guide me for storing only timeStamp without date

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a function or a user define function which is going to take as a parameter the current column and then turn it into time. You can take yhis code as an example :

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
val minuteFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:SS")
val currentMinuteAsString = minuteFormat.format(now)
```

Comment: My column contains timestamp in string format. "7:08:9 -400", I want to convert to timestamp for storing into database. expected output is " 07:08:09"

Comment: If i understand very well your input data is : "7:08:9 -400" and you want to convert it into this :  07:08:09

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.